# How to move between two layouts in java

Tags: java, swing

I am currently developing a java application

since Im a noob

I dont have any idea how to move between two initcomponent view

for example when the user click search than the whole view change to a new view with different classes

than there are some cases that the user press the back button then go to the previous view

and how to pass the parameters between the two view

thx I'll appreciate your reply

Comment: no way around reading a basic Swing textbook and/or tutorial, like f.i. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Comment: Changing the layout just changes the layout. There isn't any need for passing variables. You would use the variables in the same way for both "views".

Answer (score 6):

probably you have look at [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), then there no needed create a new Window or another separated View

Comment: Yeah I already know cardlayout and Im dont plan to use it I just want to know how to make another window tq btw

Comment: what's is another Window, 1) new window on the screen 2) swaping betweens two or more (for example) JPanels in one Window, if 2nd option  then there no better solutions in compare with CardLayout, follows example from tutorial or here http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1440__CardLayout.htm

Comment: @Carlo, That comment confirmed your "noob" status.